# If string exists, replace cell with NA

Tags: r

I have a data frame as follows:

```
Col1    Col2     Col3     Col4    Col5
   U    N=>A       {N       A}      NA
   V      {L     E=>e        E      e}
   X    M=>P       {M       P}      NA
   Y      {Z     Q=>p        Q      p}
```

How do I do the following?

1. Replace any cells that contain `=>` with `NA`.
2. Remove `{` and `}` from the data frame.

Final output to look like is this:

```
Col1    Col2     Col3     Col4    Col5
   U      NA        N        A      NA
   V       L       NA        E       e
   X      NA        M        P      NA
   Y       Z       NA        Q       p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop over the columns, use `grepl` to find the elements that have `=>`, `replace` it with `NA` and then replace the additional non-alphabetic characters with `gsub`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) gsub("[{}]+", "", replace(x, grepl("=>", x), NA)))
df1
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4 Col5
#1    U <NA>    N    A <NA>
#2    V    L <NA>    E    e
#3    X <NA>    M    P <NA>
#4    Y    Z <NA>    Q    p
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("U", "V", "X", "Y"), Col2 = c("N=>A", 
"{L", "M=>P", "{Z"), Col3 = c("{N", "E=>e", "{M", "Q=>p"), Col4 = c("A}", 
"E", "P}", "Q"), Col5 = c(NA, "e}", NA, "p}")), .Names = c("Col1", 
"Col2", "Col3", "Col4", "Col5"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -4L))
```

Comment: This is great, would it be possible to do this just for { and } ? My actual dataset has non-alphabetic characters so it removes all of those as well.

Comment: @NickKnauer  Updated the post